# Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 upgrade is in Arabic. How to make it English again

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I have done the free upgrade to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1. The only problem is it’s all in Arabic.

I speak English and live in the UK. Because it is in Arabic I cant even use Google translate to decipher what the words mean.

Can any one help? This is killing me.

Comment: Install a language pack

Comment: @Ramhound Come on be more sympathetic. Being stuck in an unknown language UI is the most disabling experience ever. E.g. do you know which button to press on this Chinese keyboard to start the language pack install? http://cdn.sett.com/images/user/20131230/kanjikeyboard70b9c7ac638290698ed063dbf307c843.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Method 1: Powershell (this is what ultimately worked)

Prereq: keyboard inputs must be in English

1. Press Windows button and type 'powershell'
2. Press enter
3. Type the following: `Set-WinUILanguageOverride en-US`
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Wait until done
6. Reboot

#### Method 2: Windows UI Settings

1. Press the 'windows' key or click the windows/start menu button
2. Click the 'down arrow' in the bottom left of the screen
3. Find "PC Settings" based on the icon:

   [image]
4. In that new window click the 3rd option from the bottom on the left side
5. Then click the second item down on the left sidebar
6. The top menu is a dropdown, go to the bottom up it and then press the up arrow 13 times. Apply settings and you should be good.