# Some of my Windows 10 is in Arabic after upgrading from Windows 8.1 and cleanup to fix some of this. How do I make the rest of it English?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I did the update from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 but it ended up all being in Arabic. I posted a question the other night and [Abraxas posted a good step -by-step fix](https://superuser.com/a/1026989/167207).

But some of it is still in Arabic. Random things.

Like when I access the media sharing on my smart TV the folders are all in Arabic. And my file locations:

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

If I type **Language** in the windows menu then I get this:

> [image]

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have found a solution:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-the-display-language

The steps were not exactly as per the solution so I searched for Control Panel and then followed the rest of the steps. It brought me to a settings page similar to the one in the answer above but not exactly the same. So it would appear this page has an influence on the Language settings too.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry Windows 10 supports changing the default language,
Just type settings in CORTANA Search (available in desktop) and open it, In that settings page select Time & Language ( icon will be alphabetic A and clock over it) Check the image which i have uploaded for your reference from there you can change your preferred language.

Get settings from Cortana from desktop.

[image: Settings]

Selecting Time and Language.

[image: Settings Page]

Changing English language from add language option.
[image: Language]

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. This is the process I did to change from completely Arabic to English. But I still have the odd arabic reference as you can see from the pictures above. Mostly file location names and titles in the windows menu. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit late, but I think it would be helpful for someone has the same issue.

Got to “settings”:

> [image]

Select “Time & Language”:

> [image]

Click on “Language” from left menu:

> [image]

Click on “Administrative Language Settings” from top right corner:

> [image]

A new window will pop-up. Select “Change System Local”:

> [image]

From the drop-down menu, Select the English language or any language you want:

> [image]

Click OK and restart your computer.
Done.

I hope this will help.